# Duplicate result of Hazealcast Predicate while querying with "in"

Tags: hazelcast, predicate, hazelcast-imap

I query Hazelcast data map using Predicate with "in" condition like below.

```
    List<String> liveVideoSourceIdList=new ArrayList(){"my_filter"};

    Predicate predicate=Predicates.in("myField",liveVideoSourceIdList.toArray(new String[0]));
```

When i filter map with the created predicate,all the values are duplicated.

If i use "like" instead of "in" like below,no duplication happens. Is there any thoughts about this problem ?

```
     Predicate   predicate=Predicates.like("myField",liveVideoSourceIdList.get(0));
```

Comment: Hey sahin, we're looking into it. So far it sounds like a bug.

Comment: Thank you  noctarius .We are waiting for your replay.

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to reproduce your issue, using 3.9-SNAPSHOT
which version are you using ?

I am using

```
    int min = random.nextInt( keyDomain - range );
    int max = min+range;

    String values = new String();
    for (int i = min; i < max ; i++) {
        values += i+", ";
    }

    SqlPredicate sqlPredicate = new SqlPredicate("personId IN ("+values+")");
    Collection<Personable> res = map.values(sqlPredicate);

    if(res.size()!=range){
        throw new AssertionException(sqlPredicate+" on map "+map.getName()+" returned "+res.size()+" expected "+range);
    }

    Set<Personable> set = new HashSet<Personable>(res);
    if(res.size()!=set.size()){
        throw new AssertionException(sqlPredicate+" on map "+map.getName()+" returned Duplicates");
    }

    for (Personable person : res) {
        if(person.getPersonId() < min || person.getPersonId() >= max ){
            throw new AssertionException(map.getName()+" "+person+" != "+sqlPredicate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Danny but we are not using SqlPredicate, we use Predicate.The version of hazelcast in our side is 3.7.2.

Comment: i am using import com.hazelcast.query.SqlPredicate;

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce your issue using 
Predicate predicate= Predicates.in("personId", values);